# Laravel api is giving 404 and is not working in my app

Tags: laravel, api

I have watched a tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xYsUKrKe_OI, in its first 5 minutes, i got a problem.
what I did so far is. I went to file `api.php` and I wrote the below code :

```php
Route::get('/person',function(){
   $person = [
       'first_name' => 'arash',
       'last_name' => 'samandar',
       'age' => 31,
   ] ;
   return $person;
});
```

but when i go to the URL i should go which is `http://localhost:8000/api/person` or even tried `http://localhost:8000/api/v1/person` or even `http://localhost:8000/person` i get bellow error :

```
{
message: "404 Not Found",
status_code: 404,
debug: {
line: 161,
file: "D:\Laravel_Projects\shianchi\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\RouteCollection.php",
class: "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException",
trace: [
"#0 D:\Laravel_Projects\shianchi\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php(766): Illuminate\Routing\RouteCollection->match(Object(Dingo\Api\Http\Request))",
"#1 D:\Laravel_Projects\shianchi\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php(621): Illuminate\Routing\Router->findRoute(Object(Dingo\Api\Http\Request))",
"#2 D:\Laravel_Projects\shianchi\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php(607): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatchToRoute(Object(Dingo\Api\Http\Request))",
"#3 D:\Laravel_Projects\shianchi\vendor\dingo\api\src\Routing\Adapter\Laravel.php(81): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatch(Object(Dingo\Api\Http\Request))",
"#4 D:\Laravel_Projects\shianchi\vendor\dingo\api\src\Routing\Router.php(513): Dingo\Api\Routing\Adapter\Laravel->dispatch(Object(Dingo\Api\Http\Request), 'v1')",
"#5 D:\Laravel_Projects\shianchi\vendor\dingo\api\src\Http\Middleware\Request.php(126): Dingo\Api\Routing\Router->dispatch(Object(Dingo\Api\Http\Request))",
"#6 D:\Laravel_Projects\shianchi\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(151): Dingo\Api\Http\Middleware\Request->Dingo\Api\Http\Middleware\{closure}(Object(Dingo\Api\Http\Request))",
"#7 D:\Laravel_Projects\shianchi\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode.php(46): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Dingo\Api\Http\Request))",
"#8 D:\Laravel_Projects\shianchi\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(137): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(Object(Dingo\Api\Http\Request), Object(Closure))",
"#9 D:\Laravel_Projects\shianchi\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(104): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Dingo\Api\Http\Request))",
"#10 D:\Laravel_Projects\shianchi\vendor\dingo\api\src\Http\Middleware\Request.php(127): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))",
"#11 D:\Laravel_Projects\shianchi\vendor\dingo\api\src\Http\Middleware\Request.php(103): Dingo\Api\Http\Middleware\Request->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Dingo\Api\Http\Request))",
"#12 D:\Laravel_Projects\shianchi\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(137): Dingo\Api\Http\Middleware\Request->handle(Object(Dingo\Api\Http\Request), Object(Closure))",
"#13 D:\Laravel_Projects\shianchi\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php(33): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))",
"#14 D:\Laravel_Projects\shianchi\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(104): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))",
"#15 D:\Laravel_Projects\shianchi\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel.php(150): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))",
"#16 D:\Laravel_Projects\shianchi\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel.php(117): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))",
"#17 D:\Laravel_Projects\shianchi\public\index.php(55): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))",
"#18 D:\Laravel_Projects\shianchi\server.php(21): require_once('D:\\Laravel_Proj...')",
"#19 {main}"
]
}
}
```

I don't use `Linux` , i use `Windows 10` , and i have not installed `valet`
Please Help Me , what should i do :( . thank you for your help beforehand.

Comment: runt the command `php artisan route:list` to get a list of all the routes declared in your application

Comment: thanks . i did it , and i have the route

Comment: @N69S what do you think the cause of this error is ?

Comment: Sometimes its happened for cache .  Clear cache and re surve your laravel app.. that should work.

Comment: How are you hosting the server? Are you running `php artisan serve` or some other way?

Answer (score 0):

I Fount at the Solution :

1 ) my first mistake was that i didn't have the `Dingo` package , and should have istalled and configured it . 
you just need to watch this video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r40yAZAi6PQ&t=405s

2 ) then in your . `api.php` you would have bellow code :

```
<?php


return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Standards Tree
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Versioning an API with Dingo revolves around content negotiation and
    | custom MIME types. A custom type will belong to one of three
    | standards trees, the Vendor tree (vnd), the Personal tree
    | (prs), and the Unregistered tree (x).
    |
    | By default the Unregistered tree (x) is used, however, should you wish
    | to you can register your type with the IANA. For more details:
    | https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6838
    |
    */

    'standardsTree' => env('API_STANDARDS_TREE', 'x'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | API Subtype
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Your subtype will follow the standards tree you use when used in the
    | "Accept" header to negotiate the content type and version.
    |
    | For example: Accept: application/x.SUBTYPE.v1+json
    |
    */

    'subtype' => env('API_SUBTYPE', 'wego'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default API Version
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This is the default version when strict mode is disabled and your API
    | is accessed via a web browser. It's also used as the default version
    | when generating your APIs documentation.
    |
    */

    'version' => env('API_VERSION', 'v1'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default API Prefix
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | A default prefix to use for your API routes so you don't have to
    | specify it for each group.
    |
    */

    'prefix' => env('API_PREFIX', 'api'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default API Domain
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | A default domain to use for your API routes so you don't have to
    | specify it for each group.
    |
    */

    'domain' => env('API_DOMAIN', null),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Name
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When documenting your API using the API Blueprint syntax you can
    | configure a default name to avoid having to manually specify
    | one when using the command.
    |
    */

    'name' => env('API_NAME', "WEGOBAZAAR API"),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Conditional Requests
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Globally enable conditional requests so that an ETag header is added to
    | any successful response. Subsequent requests will perform a check and
    | will return a 304 Not Modified. This can also be enabled or disabled
    | on certain groups or routes.
    |
    */

    'conditionalRequest' => env('API_CONDITIONAL_REQUEST', true),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Strict Mode
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Enabling strict mode will require clients to send a valid Accept header
    | with every request. This also voids the default API version, meaning
    | your API will not be browsable via a web browser.
    |
    */

    'strict' => env('API_STRICT', false),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Debug Mode
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Enabling debug mode willAPI_DEBUG=true
 result in error responses caused by thrown
    | exceptions to have a "debug" key that will be populated with
    | more detailed information on the exception.
    |
    */

    'debug' => env('API_DEBUG',true),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Generic Error Format
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When some HTTP exceptions are not caught and dealt with the API will
    | generate a generic error response in the format provided. Any
    | keys that aren't replaced with corresponding values will be
    | removed from the final response.
    |
    */

    'errorFormat' => [
        'message' => ':message',
        'errors' => ':errors',
        'code' => ':code',
        'status_code' => ':status_code',
        'debug' => ':debug',
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | API Middleware
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Middleware that will be applied globally to all API requests.
    |
    */

    'middleware' => [

    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Authentication Providers
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | The authentication providers that should be used when attempting to
    | authenticate an incoming API request.
    |
    */

    'auth' => [
        'jwt' => 'Dingo\Api\Auth\Provider\JWT',

    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Throttling / Rate Limiting
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Consumers of your API can be limited to the amount of requests they can
    | make. You can create your own throttles or simply change the default
    | throttles.
    |
    */

    'throttling' => [

    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Response Transformer
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Responses can be transformed so that they are easier to format. By
    | default a Fractal transformer will be used to transform any
    | responses prior to formatting. You can easily replace
    | this with your own transformer.
    |
    */

    'transformer' => env('API_TRANSFORMER', Dingo\Api\Transformer\Adapter\Fractal::class),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Response Formats
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Responses can be returned in multiple formats by registering different
    | response formatters. You can also customize an existing response
    | formatter.
    |
    */

    'defaultFormat' => env('API_DEFAULT_FORMAT', 'json'),

    'formats' => [

        'json' => Dingo\Api\Http\Response\Format\Json::class,

    ],

];
```

and in your `web.php` or if you use the older version `routes.php` you would write Bellow code first to define the `$api` variable :

```
$api = app('Dingo\Api\Routing\Router');

$api->version('v1', ['namespace' => 'App\Http\Controllers'], function ($api) {
   $api->get('/jsonPars','HomeController@myJson');
});
```

hope this helps you , if it deed , thumps UP :) .